# How to define custom Max order amount input field for flat shipping rate method? (Magento2)

Tags: magento2, module, shipping-methods

I want to add an input field called "max order amount" for my flat rate shipping method, so that it is hidden when the order amount is higher than the configured amount.

What possible changes i have to do in code for achieving this condition please let me know in detail as i am beginner :)

### Edit:

Ok guys so for that i find a file where i write this code in
`vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`

```
<field id="flat_shipping_subtotal" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Max Order Amount</label>
    <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
</field>
```

inside my flat shipping method. It now shows text field in the administration panel, but obviously its not working yet. I guess I must define somewhere else how to enforce the restriction. Where would that be?

Comment: Did you [read this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html)?

Comment: yes most of them pages